# Is MVC a pattern or Architecture or Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

What is pattern? What is Architecture? What is Framework?

What is MVC?

Is MVC a pattern or Architecture or Framework?

--
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is pattern?

Some standard way of developing software of specific type

> What is Architecture?

The design of a software

> What is Framework?

A set of tools allowing to build software

> What is MVC?

A software architecture pattern.

On the other hand ASP.NET MVC is framework for developing web applications using the MVC architecture pattern.